# Plotting data in R; error: default method not implemented for type 'list'

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to plot data in ggplot (I tried a CRAN version from github too), but I end up getting an error:

```
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

This is the code for the plot:

```
ggplot(SinglePatient, aes(x = Condition, y = new, fill = Session)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", color = 'black', size = 1, position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom ="errorbar", width = .1, size = 1, position = position_dodge(width=.9))+
  xlab("Condition") + ylab("Reaction time (ms)") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  plot_theme
```

This is an example of data from the data.frame that I am using:

```
Patient  Session   Stimulus     Trial  Running[Trial]   Block   ACC     Side   Condition  Group  new.RT
7212      post      blue_color.jpg  14  Center2ExpTrialList 2   incorrect   L   Center2Exp  BrainHQ  251    
7212      post      brown_color.jpg 6   Center2ExpTrialList 2   correct     R   Center2Exp  BrainHQ  253
7212      post      blue_color.jpg  19  Center2ExpTrialList 2   correct     L   Center2Exp  BrainHQ  256
7212      post      brown_color.jpg 23  Center2ExpTrialList 12  correct     R   Center2Exp  BrainHQ  261    
7212      post      blue_color.jpg  18  Center2ExpTrialList 2   correct     L   Center2Exp  BrainHQ  267
```

Any idea of what I need to change? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Is `SinglePatient` of class data.frame or list? Would be great if we could reproduce the error with a piece of data or with an included dataset.

Comment: @teunbrand It is a data.frame. I edited my original post so that it includes a piece of data from SinglePatient.

Comment: When I run your plotting code with the data you provided I also get an error but not the same one as yours. At my end, there was no `new` column in the data, but once I substituted that with `new.RT`, I managed to get a plot. I couldn't run the `+ plot_theme` you have as that is not a variable I have. Could you check wether omitting the theme, or replacing `new` with `new.RT` would help?

Comment: @teunbrand ```plot_theme``` is an object in the different part of the code. I apologize for missing that part. when I replace ```new``` with ```new.RT``` I get an error that basically says that ```object new.RT not found``` (which I found confusing before). Just tried omitting the theme, got the error ```Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale```. I am puzzled.

Comment: That is weird, since your example data.frame contains 'new.RT' as a column. The last error is often when trying to supply factors or characters to a numeric scale.

Comment: @teunbrand tried running the code on coworkers computer, got same issues, including ```new.RT not found```. As for the last error, all of my variables are numeric so... Another thing is that the new.RT column is a combination of two other columns that I did not use in my example data. Perhaps, something went wrong when I made the new.RT column in the first place.

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(your_example_data)` such that the column classes and such are the exact same?

Comment: @teunbrand solved my issue. when you said that you were able to plot data I started thinking that the main issue was the ```new.RT``` column. Turned out that I messed up in the other part of the code that ultimately created the ```new.RT``` column. thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Ah good, I'm glad it worked out in the end

Answer (score 14):

The solution for when I encountered this issue is to run `unlist` on the columns you are giving to ggplot. The issue seems to be that ggplot doesn't want to plot things that are lists, and the problem was not solved by downloading the latest version of ggplot either. You may have inadvertently made the data you are giving it a list.

I solved this by simply doing the following:

`dataframe$column <- unlist(dataframe$column)`

Issue: data is somehow in a list format.

Solution: `unlist()`

Comment: Can also just convert the data to a dataframe that resolved the issue for me. My issue was that manipulating the dataframe with dplyr converted the dataframe into a tibble, which causes lots of issues down the line. SinglePatient = as.data.frame(SinglePatient).

Answer (score 2):

Convert your data/list into a `data.frame`

```r
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)
```